# Integrating ShareThis with Next.js

Tags: next.js, sharethis

Has anyone tried to integrate ShareThis with Next.js?

I'm getting "Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server." and this, I have ascertained, is down to the inclusion of the ShareThis script tag.

I'm not sure what I need to do in order to resolve this error.

This is my _document.tsx file, containing the offending script tag:

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

const Document = () => (
  <Html>
    <Head>

      <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src={`https://platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SHARETHIS_PROPERTY_ID}&product=sop`}
        async
        defer
      ></script>
    </Head>

    <body>
      <Main />

      <NextScript />
    </body>
  </Html>
);

export default Document;
```

Of course, the NEXT_PUBLIC_SHARETHIS_PROPERTY_ID variable from my .env file is being correctly populated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `next/script` to load 3rd party scripts like ShareThis. Here's their documentation https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script

Make sure to apply the `<Script src="" />` component OUTSIDE of the `next/head` component, either above of below it.

Hope this helps.